# Parse and Find strings in an email address using AppleScript with Outlook

Tags: email, outlook, applescript

I am trying to create custom rules for received emails in Outlook 2016 on a Mac. I need to examine the recipients to check for some addresses. I have the following code, but I am stuck when it comes time to look at the address for debugging purposes

```
tell application "Microsoft Outlook"
    set theMessages to messages of folder "Inbox" of exchange account "myact"
    repeat with aMessage in theMessages
        set sSubject to subject of aMessage as text
        set sSender to address of (get aMessage's sender)
        set tContent to content of aMessage as text
        repeat with i from 1 to count of to recipients of aMessage
            set sTo to email address of (get aMessage's to recipient i) as text
            display dialog sTo
        end repeat
    end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: You said, "but I am stuck when it comes time to look at the address for debugging purposes" yet you have not expressed how you're stuck or what you expect, etc.  If you want help debugging code, then your question should conform to [How to create a Minimal, Complete,and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I don't have Outlook so I can't test anything specific to it, however I'd create a [`list`](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_classes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH1g-BBCDBHIE) and then use [control statements](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-157332) to see if the target is in the list and then act accordingly. E.g. `if theList contains thisAddress then` ...

Comment: @user3439894 you are right. I wasn't very clear. I was getting an error logging "sTo". Forgot what the error was. I fixed it below.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by replacing 
    set sTo to email address of (get aMessage's to recipient i) as text

with
    set sTo to address of (get (aMessage's cc recipient i)'s email address)